# How can i have acces to a modified element with a js file from another one?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 2 javascript files on the same page.
the first one modifies the content of an element in the page and adds some text inside the paragraph. It works just perfectly. In the second file I want to get the text inside the modified element but I just get the initial text in the page and not the modified one with the first javascript file.
So basically my 2nd javasript can't read the innerText of the element.

```
 <p class="right">Tax Total:
    <span id="total-commande"></span>
 </p>
```

first js file :

```
document.getElementById("total-commande").appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)} $`))
```

second js file:

```
 var T = document.getElementById("total-commande")
```

Comment: Please may you add a [mcve] of the issue? I can guess what the solution might be, but it'd be better if you showed us a demo, rather than explaining it to us

Comment: make sure your 2nd file is imported after the first one in HTML so they execute in order and you can use defer as well to control the loading on the scripts. If it still does not work please share a working link on jsbin or jsfiddle would be happy to help

Comment: I just modified the question to add some examples. Thanks for both of you

Comment: from what you said,
it seems that your second script get the value before the first script changes the value.

in order to make things work as you wish you need to add a delay in the script execution.

a simple setTimeout() will help you, if you need more detailed answer please add additional details.

change your second file like this,

setTimeout(()=>{
 var T = document.getElementById("total-commande");
})

Comment: the setTimeOut() should be added in the html file ?

Comment: no in the second script file, setTimeout(()=>{ var T = document.getElementById("total-commande"); })